# About smooth function whose reciprocal is also smooth

Tags: analyticity, smooth-manifolds

I know that for exponential functions $e^{at}$, or functions like $1/t^m$, t>0, both they and their reciprocals are smooth. Could you please give me more classes of smooth functions, or Analytic class that could meet this requirement?

Thanks. Shuxia

Comment: If you take $any$ smooth function that doesn't vanish anywhere on its domain, then its reciprocal will also be smooth.